# Usernames in a UDP chat server with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, udp, server, client, chat

I'm setting up a simple chat server with NodeJS that only uses a server and client. It works, and I can open up multiple client windows on the same machine, but now I need a bit more.

I would like to:

- Give each client the option to set usernames
- Have a client request current time from server
- Action commands like "/me punches the warlock" that the server shows others as "User punches the warlock"

This sounds like a quick days work, but I just started looking at UDP and I can't quite find any examples online other than a generic server/client thing that sends and gets messages. How would I go about those tasks?
Code:

Server.js:

```
var dgram = require('dgram'); //import datagram to get everything needed for UDP

var PORT = 22222;
var CLIENT_PORT = 2223;

// An IP address that's reserved on each network
// Gets sent to the server
var ADDRESS = "-"; //dont want to show my IP :)

var sock = dgram.createSocket({reuseAddr: true, type: 'udp4'}); //can now open multiple clients

var current_time = Date.now(); //?

function sendMessage(data) {
    sock.send(data, 0, data.length, PORT, ADDRESS, function(err){
       if(err){
            throw err;
       }
    });
}

sock.on("message", function(data, rinfo) {
    //listen for messages and print them
    console.log(data);

    //Check if the client's port was equal to the port to find client data on
  //If so, get packet
  if (rinfo.port === CLIENT_PORT) {
    console.log('\nreceived');

    //call function to broadcast the data out to everyone on the local network
    sendMessage(data);
 }


//Get the string data from the data buffer.
var stringData = data.toString(); //also could be toJSON()
console.log(stringData);

//Convert that string back into a buffer by making a new Buffer and passing it in.
//The buffer class can take a string, an array or just a number of bytes to allocate to memory
var backToBuffer = new Buffer(stringData); //can take a string, array or just a size to allocate
console.log(backToBuffer);

});

//This opens the connection and starts listening
//(Client Port, Address to listen to which is ALL, What to do)
sock.bind(CLIENT_PORT, '', function(){

    sock.setBroadcast(true);
    console.log('listening on port ' + PORT + "\n"); 

});
```

Client.js:

```
var dgram = require('dgram');

var SERVER_PORT = 22222;
var PORT = 22223;

var ADDRESS = "-";

//read input from the command line
var stdin = process.stdin;
var stdout = process.stdout;

var sock = dgram.createSocket({reuseAddr: true, type: 'udp4'});

var server_sock = dgram.createSocket({reuseAddr: true, type: 'udp4'});

function sendMessage(data) {
//onsole.log("sending data");
    sock.send(data, 0, data.length, PORT, ADDRESS, function(err) {
        if(err) {
             throw err;
        }
        //nsole.log("sent");
    });
}

server_sock.on("message", function(data, rinfo) {
    console.log("received " + data.toString());
});

server_sock.bind(SERVER_PORT, '', function() {
    console.log('listening to server port');
});

sock.bind(PORT, '', function() {
    sock.setBroadcast(true);
    console.log("please enter a message\n");

    stdin.resume();

    stdin.on("data", function(data) {
        sendMessage(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js has loads of libraries to make realtime communication chats, I don't understand the choice of using UDP and managing everything by yourself, and it also looks that you are not very expert on this. My suggestion is to use a websocket library like it can be socket.io which they even have an example of a simple chat in their website http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Using socket.io (or similar) it will help you a lot since it has sessions so you can save the username and return it everytime you post a message.
Below I wrote a small example of the server side (took from the index.js of the get-started above).

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    var username = 'RANDOM';
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    //here you should catch messages starting with "/" and parse them to write a different message
    io.emit('chat message', username + ': ' msg);
  });
  socket.on('update username', function(msg) {
    username = msg;
    io.emit('username changed', username);
  });
});
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: My problem is that I need to read user input. I do not need socket.io for this, but rather, the readline method here: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html. Thank you, though, socket looks good for future projects.

Comment: You can read input and then send via socket.io. or maybe i just did not get the point